# Does a function that calls a Future needs to be a Future too?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have a function that calls a Future in it. Now I am not sure if the first function needs to be a future too to await for the data. Here is my code:

```
  FireBaseHandler handler = FireBaseHandler();

  saveRows() {
    handler.saveRows(plan.planId, plan.rows); ///this is a future
  }
```

In my FireBaseHandler class I have this Future:

```
  final CollectionReference usersCol =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future saveRows(String id, data) async {
    return await usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).collection('plans').doc(id)
        .update({'rows': data});
  }
```

So does the first function needs to be a Future too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have `async` function inside a `sync` function. But this way you lose ability to `await` for the result. And `await` is allowed only in functions marked as `async`, which leads us to `Future` as a the result of that function. So, yes, if you need to wait for the result, both functions have to be `Future` functions.

Edit:
If you need your wrapper function to be `sync`, but still be able to retrieve the result from inner `async` function, you can use a callback:

```
  saveRows(Function(dynamic) callback) {
    handler.saveRows(plan.planId, plan.rows).then((result){
      callback(result);
});
  }
```

This way the result will be retrieved at any point of time after calling the function (the code is not `await`ed)